# Installing Xdebug for php5.5.38 in Mac

Tags: php, xdebug

Since php5.5.* reached  end of support, there are not lot of ways which allows one to install xdebug for it in mac(I think it's the same case for any other OS).  Is there a way to install xdebug for php5.5(specifially php5.5.38)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ports in mac, then you can easily install php5.5.38(default version of php in mac ports when the version is 5.5 ) with `port install php55` and xdebug for that version with `port install php55-xdebug`.